How to download elevation GeoTIFF from Copernicus GLO30 DEM using Earth Engine API for Python?
I was working on a project in geospatial analysis, where I need to download GeoTIFF files for elevation data. I decided to use the Copernicus GLO30 DEM found in Google Earth Engine, because it is the most up-to-date, and it also contains high resolution topography data.
I tried writing this simple code in python to try and bulk download elevation GeoTIFF's and I was expecting it to run smoothly and download GeoTIFF's that I can view in Windows Photo Viewer, as well as a dedicated software such as Google Earth Pro. However, even though the code runs without errors, the GeoTIFF shows up as a blank white square instead of the usual grayscale depiction of topography. Here is my code:
import ee
import requests

# Initialize the Earth Engine module
ee.Initialize(project='your-project-id')

# Function to read coordinates from a file
def read_coordinates(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        # Assuming the file contains one coordinate pair per line in "lat,lon" format
        coordinates = [tuple(map(float, line.strip().split(','))) for line in lines]
    return coordinates

# Read coordinates from the specified file
coordinates = read_coordinates('coordinates.txt')

# Loop through each coordinate pair and process elevation data
for lat, lon in coordinates:
    # Create a point from the coordinates
    point = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat)

    # Define a 1 mile x 1 mile square around the point
    buffer_distance = 804.67  # Half of 1 mile in meters
    roi = point.buffer(buffer_distance).bounds()

    # Load the Copernicus Digital Elevation Model (DEM) as an ImageCollection
    copernicus_dem = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30")

    # Check if there are any images in the collection
    if copernicus_dem.size().getInfo() == 0:
        print(f'No images found in Copernicus DEM for coordinates: {lat}, {lon}.')
        continue

    # Use mosaic to combine images and clip to ROI
    elevation_data = copernicus_dem.mosaic().clip(roi)

    # Generate a download URL for the image
    download_url = elevation_data.getDownloadURL({
        'scale': 30,  # Scale in meters
        'region': roi.getInfo()['coordinates'],
        'format': 'GeoTIFF'
    })

    # Download the GeoTIFF file
    response = requests.get(download_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Save the file locally with a unique name based on coordinates
        filename = f'elevation_data_{lat}_{lon}.tif'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f'Downloaded: {filename}')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to download data for coordinates: {lat}, {lon}. Status code: {response.status_code}')

Note, in order to use this project you will have to run pip install earthengine-api and then earthengine authenticate in your terminal, or ee.authenticate() in python.
This code run's without any errors, so it has been difficult to know what exactly is going wrong. However, it could also be that my machine is glitching with opening the GeoTIFF files, as they are not a common image format and contain extra metadata.
I would really appreciate it if you all could tell me how to get the code to work, or if it works fine and my window's just can't handle the file format.
Thanks,
Arnav
